# MongoDB - add doc to list of docs (if unique)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Given this document structure:

```
{
    "_id": date,
    "list": [
        { hour: "something",
          hour: "something else"
        }
    ]
}
```

1. How do I upsert a new doc based on the _id?
2. How do I check to see if a key exists in my sub document and upsert to that?

What I've tried:

```
col.update({'_id':my_str}, {'_id':my_str, 'list':{'$addtoset':["14":"yet another thing"]}}, {'$upsert':'true'})
```

EDIT:

updated my structure:

```
{
    _id: date,
    hours: [
                { "0": "something"},
                { "1": "something else"},
                  ...
            ]
}
```

Comment: you structure is strange. you have a list of 1 element containing an associative array?

Comment: Is there a better way to structure my data?

Comment: for one, `list` should not be called list, it is confusing. ('hours' could be suitable). Then it probably should be a dict rather than a list. Finally, have you considered mongoengine?

Comment: Isn't that a django tool?

Comment: no. that's a python Object-Document Mapper for MongoDB. You can use it with any python script/app/whatever that uses mongodb. It allows you to use objects with fields instead of raw mongo documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify directly the internal list attribute with pymongo, need to pull the whole document and republish it:

```
my_doc = col.find_one({'_id': my_str})
if my_doc is not None:
    # Document exist, modify it
    my_doc['hours'].append({"14": "yet another thing"})
    col.update({'_id': my_str}, my_doc)
else:
    # Insert the new document with all the new attributes
    col.insert({'_id': my_str, 'hours': [{"14": "yet another thing"}]})
```

Comment: What if {"14":"a string"} is already in there? would this update the existing sub doc or just append to it?

Comment: Since your data structure is a list, it would add a duplicate. If you want to have unique values then 'hours' should be a dictionary, not a list (in that case, value of hours[14] would be replaced by the new string)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up going with what you said, but I changed my structure to be a list of dictionaries.